# Solidity Infinite Loop

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, unittesting

I was creating a game of Casino Roulette using ChainLink's VRF Coordinator and Automation. I am stuck in "seemingly" an infinite loop in the following function:

```
    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /*_requestId*/,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {

        string[] memory table = s_table;
        Bet[] memory bets = s_bets;

        uint256 randomElementIndex = randomWords[0] % 38;
        string memory randomElementSelected = table[randomElementIndex];
        emit ElementSelected(randomElementSelected);
        console.log(randomElementSelected);

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < bets.length; i++){
            bool isWinningBet = false;
            for (uint256 j = 0; j < bets[i].betElements.length; j++){
                if(keccak256(bytes(normalizeString(bets[i].betElements[j]))) == 
                    keccak256(bytes(normalizeString(randomElementSelected)))) {
                        isWinningBet = true;
                        console.log(isWinningBet); //this is printing
                        s_wonBets.push(bets[i]);
                        emit BetWon(bets[i]);
                }
            }

            if(!isWinningBet) {
                emit BetLost(bets, randomElementSelected);
            }
        }

        delete s_bets;
        s_betState = BetState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimestamp = block.timestamp;

    }
```

In this function `Bet` is a struct I created to keep track of all the bets being placed.

```
    struct Bet {
        address payable player;
        string[] betElements;
        uint256 betAmount;
        bool isInsideBet;
    }
```

Here's my `normalizeString` helper function:

```
    function normalizeString(string memory _element) internal pure returns(string memory){
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_element));
    }
```

The bets are being placed in a separate function and are stored in `s_bets`.
The idea is to pick a random element from the table and check if it exists in the `betElements` of `s_bets` if the picked element is found in the `s_bets` the function emits the event `BetWon` else it will emit `BetLost`.

I did some unit tests and the issue is that while the test listens for the the event `BetWon` it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop and then fails with the error:

```
Error: Timeout of 500000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Here's the unit test for the `fulfillRandomWords()`

```
        describe("fulfillRandomWords", function () {
            beforeEach(async function () {
                const entrance = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
                await roulette.connect(playerSigner).enterRoulette({ value: entrance });
                const betAmountPlaced = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.030");
                const bet = {
                    player: player,
                    betElements: ["13B", "14R", "15B", "16R", "17B", "18R", "19R", "20B", "21R", "22B", "23R", "24B"],
                    betAmount: betAmountPlaced,
                    isInsideBet: false,
                }
                //["13B", "14R", "15B", "16R", "17B", "18R", "19R", "20B", "21R", "22B", "23R", "24B"],
                await roulette.connect(playerSigner).placeBet(bet, { value: betAmountPlaced });
                await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1]);
                await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
            });
            it("Can only be called after performUpkeep", async function () {
                await expect(vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(0, roulette.address)
                ).to.be.revertedWith("nonexistent request");
            });

            //Dat massive promise test *sigh*
            it("Should select a random element from the table, look for it in the bets, check if the player won",
                async function () {
                    const startingTimeStamp = await roulette.getLastTimeStamp();

                    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                        roulette.once("BetWon", async () => {
                            console.log("Bet Won event found");
                            //check the fulfillRanomWords function with the usage of s_bets and s_wonBets
                            try {
                                const bets = await roulette.getBets();
                                const betState = await roulette.getBetState();
                                const latestTimeStamp = await roulette.getLastTimeStamp();
                                const betAmountPlaced = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.030");
                                const initialBalanceOfPlayer = await ethers.provider.getBalance(player);
                                assert(bets.length == 0);
                                assert.strictEqual(betState, 0);
                                assert(latestTimeStamp.toString() > startingTimeStamp.toString());
                                // assert(wonBets.length > 0);

                                // //call to the handlePayout to send money to the winner
                                // await roulette.handlePayout();

                                // const playerBalance = await roulette.getPlayerBalance(player);
                                // const balanceOfPlayer = await ethers.provider.getBalance(player);
                                // const wonBets = await roulette.getWonBets();

                                // assert.equal(playerBalance.toString(), (betAmountPlaced.mul(2)).toString());
                                // assert.equal(balanceOfPlayer.toString(),
                                //     (betAmountPlaced.mul(2)).add(initialBalanceOfPlayer).toString());
                                // await assert.equal(wonBets.length, 0);

                                // //call to withdraw to send money to the owner
                                // const initialDeployerBalance = await roulette.provider.getBalance(deployer);
                                // const startingRouletteBalance = await roulette.provider.getBalance(roulette.address);

                                // const txResponse = await roulette.connect(deployerSigner).withdrawFunds();
                                // const txReciept = await txResponse.wait(1);
                                // const { gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice } = txReciept;
                                // const gasCost = gasUsed.mul(effectiveGasPrice);

                                // const finalRouletteBalance = await roulette.provider.getBalance(roulette.address);
                                // const finalDeployerBalance = await roulette.provider.getBalance(deployer);

                                // assert.equal(finalRouletteBalance, 0);
                                // assert.equal(startingRouletteBalance.add(initialDeployerBalance).toString(),
                                //     finalDeployerBalance.add(gasCost).toString());
                            } catch (error) {
                                reject(error);
                            }
                            resolve();
                        });
                        roulette.once("BetLost", async () => {
                            console.log("bet lost event found");
                            const wonBets = await roulette.getWonBets();
                            const bets = await roulette.getBets();
                            const betState = await roulette.getBetState();
                            assert(bets.length == 0);
                            assert(wonBets.length == 0);
                            assert.strictEqual(betState, 0);
                            resolve();
                        });
                        const transactionResponse = await roulette.performUpkeep("0x");
                        const transactionReciept = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
                        const requestId = transactionReciept.events[1].args.requestId;
                        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, roulette.address);
                    });
                });
        });
```

P.S

The test is working fine for `BetLost` event.

Comment: How many elements are you processing? Could it be that the transaction is failing, so it won't emit any event? I'll recommend against using linear searches in this type of callback. They will be too expensive. Instead you could use a mapping from `betElements` to `bets[]`, so you'll automatically have the winning bets without searching. You'll have to build the table while the bets are being done. It is extra work at the beginning but it is totally worth in my opinion.